# MATLAB - Restore central sub-section of an image

Tags: matlab

So, I have a 512x512 distorted image, but what I'm trying to do is restore only a 400x400 centrally-positioned subsection of the image while it is still distorted outside of it. How do I go about implementing something like that?

I was thinking to have a for loop within a for loop like

```
for row = 57:457
    for col = 57:457
        %some filter in here
    end
end
```

But I'm not quite sure what to do next...

Comment: What kind of distortion are you trying to restore from? If you're going to apply a filter to that section of the image, you can do something like: `image(57:457,57:457) = imfilter(image(57:457,57:457), filter);`

Comment: The distortion is some noise applied randomly to the image in a previous setting. What I want to do now is undo the process by restoring the image to its original as close as possible, but I'm not sure which process is most effective and how. The `medfilt2` function seems to work rather well, but I'm also trying to explore other options that may be more effective.

Comment: Have you tried Wiener filtering? http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/deconvwnr.html

Comment: No, but thank you for that. I will look into that. Is it possible for to apply a median filter to the following... sort of like this? I get an error, but I'd still like to use the `medfilt2`...

   `image(57:457,57:457) = medfilt2(image);`

Comment: The size doesn't match. You should apply `medfilt2` to the same region of the image you're trying to restore.

Comment: Is there a way I can still manage to use the `medfilt2` function within the 400x400 subsection? It produces a much better result than the average filter when I apply it to the whole image.

Comment: You could run `medfilt2` on the entire image, and then keep only the 400x400 part you're interested in.

Comment: But what I'm trying to do is restore the 400x400 subsection and everything outside is still distorted. I'm not sure how running the median filter will work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, you can do a lot of things in MATLAB without loops using [vectorization](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1100/1109.html) instead. As discussed in the comments below your question, there are filtering functions included with MATLAB such as `medfilt2`, `wiener2` or `imfilter` which all work on two-dimensional images directly without the need for any loops.

To restore only the center part of your image, you apply the filter to the full image, store the result in a temporary variable and then copy over the part that you want into your distored image:

```
tmpimage = medfilt2(distortedimage);
finalimage = distortedimage;
finalimage(57:456,57:456)=tmpimage(57:456,57:456);
```

Of course if you don't care about edge effects during the reconstruction, you can just call the reconstruction for the part that interests you and avoid the `tmpimage`:

```
finalimage = distortedimage;
finalimage(57:456,57:456)=medfilt2(distortedimage(57:456,57:456));
```

Note how the sizes in an assignment need to match: you can't assign `finalimage(57:456,57:456)=medfilt2(distortedimage)` since the right-hand-size produces a 512-by-512 matrix which doesn't fit into the 400-by-400 center of finalimage.